# How to get a row for each occurrence of Id in IN clause?

Tags: t-sql

Given that I have a list of repeating ids that I need to fetch some additional data to populate xls spreadsheet, how can I do that. "IN" clause returns only 1 match, but I need a row for each occurrence of an Id. I looked at PIVOT, thinking I could create a select list and then do inner join.

```
Select m.Id, m.LegalName, m.OtherId
from MyTable m
where m.OtherId in (1,2,1,1,3,1,4,4,2,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VALUES` clause :

```
SELECT t.id as OtherId,  m.id, m.LegalName
FROM ( VALUES (1),(2),(1),(1),(3),(1),(4),(4),(2),(1) 
     ) t(ID) INNER JOIN
     MyTable m
     ON m.OtherId = t.id;
```